# 401 error when trying to send a get requet to GMAIL API with access token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api, aiohttp

Hi I am trying to fetch the emails using gmail api. I have used google's boilerplate code to authorize access to my private data and an access token is created.Now I want to make a get request using 'aiohttp'. Below is the function that I have written. It gives me 401 error. What am I doing wrong?

token generator function:(this is the code provided by google in gmail api docs, I just wrapped it into a function)

```
def authenticate(self):
        """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
        Lists the user's Gmail labels.
        """
        creds = None
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        self.service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        


async def __get_email_by_id(self, id):
    url = GET_MAIL_FROM_ID_URL.format("me", id)
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(CRED['token'])}

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:

            print("Content:", await response.text())
            return json.loads(await response.text())
```

Below object is retreived from my local db, where I have stored all the emails and their ids(using code from gmail api docs). Now I am trying to fetch email using the id.

```
mail: {'_id': ObjectId('6134dfa9ac85cffb6a8d4125'), 'id': '17bb5be9d7b9eb97', 'threadId': '17bb5be9d7b9eb97'}
```

CRED object:

```
CRED = {
    "token": "ya29.a0ARrdaM-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTPHExxllfnfLXXBi87udo4eJX-gn21WPq5t2uehpaPO7bhBh0bYQNpsMKFIVucg0d0F7gI5IVwxxxxxxxx-sQ-LWuSSgQRCiguQHqn5ImGJ6aoHLRWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "refresh_token": "1//0ggpEqfxxxxxxxxxxARAAGBASNwF-L9IrfyKVwwRbTd71C0p0s3urnFjYVHvV7QDsRxsa_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_4DAB0stzCGDSJQw",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "client_id": "1xxxxxxxxx96-hpfxxxxxxxxxs16e3avje3mdgalv4h2v.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "U3xxxxxL-nxxxxxxxxxxKzGd",
    "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
    ],
    "expiry": "2021-09-07T04:24:48.509005Z"
}
```

Response:

```
Status: 401
Content: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

NOTE: The access token is not expired, the same token object is working when I try to use code provided in google docs as below.

```
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
```

Comment: How are you creating the token?  it needs to be a valid google access token.

Comment: Token is created when "authenticte" function above is called.

Comment: I wont claim to be a python expert but can you echo out CRED['token'] and verify its not null? can we agree that cred is not the same as CRED in python